# What is the Gear Shift joystic key value in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmdsq.png)

The " Thrustmaster T500RS Gear Shift " device is recognized fine, but the unique key value is not recognized in the Input Manager.

In case I used it,
I tried Joy Stick Button 0 ~ 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that unity natively supports that device. Unity doesn't support every device on the market. Every day a new steering wheel comes out. They don't add support for all of them.